# how to do the multiple tableview by using custom class in Single XIb Viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: swift

Hi i have xib files there i used create multiple table with multiple custom xib cell ...but i got the problem while load the multiple custom cell ......any one one help me to solve this issues Thanks in Advance

```
func TablecellRegisternib() {

       self.Hight_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.weight_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
         self.Gender_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
           self.Weekday_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.Gym_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "GymTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

    self.Sports_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "SpotsTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")

   self.AdditioanlSports_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "AdditioanlSpotsTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

        var count:Int?

        if tableView == self.weight_table {
            count = WightUnitArray.count
        }


        if tableView == self.Hight_table {
            count =  HightUnitArray.count

        }


        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {
            count =  WeekdayArray.count

        }

        if tableView == self.Gender_table {
            count = GenderArray.count
        }
        if tableView == self.Sports_tableview {
           count =  SportsArray.count

       }

 if tableView == self.AdditionalSports_tableview {
           count =  AdditionalSportsArray.count

       }

        return count!

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        if tableView == self.weight_table {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=WightUnitArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }

        if tableView == self.Hight_table {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=HightUnitArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }




        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=WeekdayArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }


        if tableView == self.Gender_table {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=GenderArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }


        if tableView == self.Gym_tableview {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! GymTableCell
                var GymDict = GymtableArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.sportlbl!.text = GymDict["name"] as? String

                cell.sportlbl?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                cell.sportlbl?.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
                return cell

            }

 if tableView == self.Sports_tableview {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3") as! SportsTableCell
                var SportsDict = SportsArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.sportlbl1!.text = SportsDict["name"] as? String

                cell.sportlbl1?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                cell.sportlbl1?.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
                return cell

            }



        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


          if tableView == self.weight_table {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        let row = indexPath.row

        selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?


        let weightstring = (WightUnitArray[row])
            if( weightstring != "Pound")
            {
            self.WeightUnitTabletxt.text = "kg"

            }
            else{
            self.WeightUnitTabletxt.text = "lbs"
            }

        self.Weight_View.isHidden = true
        tableView.reloadData()
            }

        if tableView == self.Hight_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            let Hightstr = (HightUnitArray[row])
            if( Hightstr != "Feet")
            {
                self.HeightUnitTabletxt.text = "m"

            }
            else{
                self.HeightUnitTabletxt.text = "ft"
            }

            self.Hight_view.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }



        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            self.FirstDayofWeek_txt.text = (WeekdayArray[row])
            self.FirstdayoftheWeek_view.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


        if tableView == self.Gender_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            self.gender_txt.text = (GenderArray[row])
            self.Genderview.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem that you have?

Comment: i cant load the data on tabelview ...i got the problem at cell row at indexpath..can u check my code is that correct..beacuse i have to using multiple custome cell

Comment: how to do the multiple cell

Comment: Why do you use so many tableViews? It is usually better to have one tableView with multiple cells.

Comment: but i have to use many tableview ..

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: its not get load the data show me nill

Comment: but  i got the array values ...its shows error when return cell at cell row atIndexpath]

Comment: if u any ans pls post to solve this issues how to do that kindly check out my code becaues i go error on my code